Can't set NFS permissions after switching networks
(EndeavourOS host, running nfsv4-server.service)
Got a QEMU/KVM VM network that I'm trying to switch to VMware. For the most part, this has been a simple process, if not a time-consuming one. The only real hangup I'm having is with the NFSv4 share permissions.
Here is my working /etc/exports from the QEMU setup:
/media/host/shared-files      192.168.122.0/24(rw,sync,insecure,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check,crossmnt,fsid=0)

When I switched to VMware, the NAT network changed to 172.16.105.0, so I figured that simply making that change in /etc/exports, re-export, then I'd be good to go. However, the only way I can get this to work is to remove the IP network/subnet masks restrictions.
This is not a firewall issue, as I can see/use the share just fine from the guests. I'm not as proficient with TCP/IP networks as I'd like, so I'm not sure what the problem is here.
Any ideas?

Does the server actually see its clients as coming from 172.16.105.0/24? Use tcpdump -n to verify that.

Thanks for this hint. When I changed the exports permissions to match the local LAN (192.168.0.0/24), the VM could mount the share. I did not see any packets to/from 172.16.105. Not sure what VMware does differently than Libvirtd. Write up an answer and I'll accept it.

Ah, it's from your main LAN, not from another VM? Then the VMware behavior sounds normal – it's the QEMU/KVM setup that is a bit weird if it causes the LAN devices' source address to change.

Well, it's working now and that's all that matters. Thanks a bunch!

Any time IP address-based rules don't seem to match, use tcpdump (or tshark or Wireshark) to verify what address is actually on the packets you're receiving.
tcpdump -n -i eth0 "tcp port 2049"

tshark -n -i eth0 -f "tcp port 2049"

From what you say in comments, your previous QEMU/KVM setup had some unusual address translation (maybe accidentally too-broad iptables SNAT rules) that caused access from the LAN to appear as if it originated locally within the VM subnet. That's not usually the way VM "NAT networks" are meant to work (nor NAT in general for that matter) – they should only SNAT traffic from within the VM network to outside, not the other way around; incoming traffic should retain its original source address, which is what happens with VMware in your case.
